# Не выполняется INSERT в БД

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Инициализация подключения к БД проходит нормально.
Прошу указать ошибку в коде, из-за которой не происходит INSERT.

Верно работающий код php:

```
<?php    
$var1 = $_GET['q'];
$var2 = $_GET['v'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost', 'root', '1234', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
$sql = "insert into `clients` (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, 'const')";
$STH = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$exec = $STH->execute(array($var1, $var2));
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php    
$var1 = $_GET['q'];
$var2 = $_GET['v'];
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost', 'root', '1234');
$sql = "insert into `mytab` (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)";
$STH = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$exec = $STH->execute(array($var1, $var2));
?>
```

Ваши ошибки:
1 - неправильный sql; 
2 - значения не передаются в `prepare`, значения нужно передавать в виде массива в `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

3 ошибка - отсутствие информирования об ошибках. Поэтому соединяться надо так:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost', 'root', '1234', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил исходный код. Однако, браузер возвращает ошибку: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' в этой строке.

Comment: Это значит что у вас php5.3 и массив надо объявлять через `array()` а не через `[]`